# Design question for abstract base class?

Tags: c++

Have a interface

```
class abc {

public:
virtual int foo() = 0;  
...

}

class concrete1: public abc { 

public:
int foo() { 

..
}


class concrete2 : public abc {

public:
int foo() {

..
}


}
```

Now in my main program I need to construct classes based upon a value of a variable

```
abc *a;
if (var == 1)
   a = new concrete1();
else
   a = new concrete2();
```

Obviously I don't want these two lines everywhere in the program (please note I have simplified here so that things are clear). What design pattern should I be using if there are any?

Comment: Don't forget your pure virtual destructor in the base class.  Also a ';' is supposed to come after the closing '}' of the class definition.

Comment: Factory as litb suggests is the basic idea, however for a less trivial case you may need to examine issues such as different arguments to constructors.

Comment: Also generally you will have some switch statement to lookup which class to use, this is fragile in itself because the addition of a new concrete class requires you to change the factory class and you may break unrelated code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use a factory or factory method as litb has mentioned.

But in addition to that I advise you to use an enum, or at least symbolic constants to determine which class to instantiate. This is much easier to read, and it allows you to build safeguards for unexpected values.